# parse_url make /store/cat1/pro4 to /store/cat1

Tags: php, string

I have this url /store/cat1/pro4 I want it to remove the /pro4, so it becomes /store/cat1

Or

If I just could extract the /cat1 from the string

How can I do this?

Comment: you can split ([explode()](http://us1.php.net/explode)) the string by `/` into an array and only take the parts you need

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @Ibu Example?? Please

Comment: @GrahamRitchie The cat1 and pro4 is could aswell be strawberry and banana.

Comment: @user3524823 see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it by spliting the string:

```
$url = "/store/cat1/pro4";
list($path,$store,$category,$product) = explode("/",$url);

echo $store;    // store
echo $category; // cat1
echo $product;  // pro4
```

Comment: works fine (after changes :-P - each time was about to comment when you noticed your mistake :-P) + 1

Comment: Yes, I didnt take the empty string before the first `/` the first time.

Comment: Thanks @Ibu Exact the code I needed. I cant accept answer within 4 minutes, because I'm new on the forum